# sql server query group by item

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns,sql server 2008

```
item, count , date
```

I would like a query that selects the total count per item for current day with 
date colums having the format 2011-03-30 09:00:00.000

```
select 
   date,item, sum(count) as total 
from 
   table1 
group by 
   date,item
```

EDIT:

```
select item, dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,date),0) as dateInserted, sum(count) 
as total from Table1 group by item, dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,date),0) order by 1
```

the first select returns totals but grouped by the datetime instead of date...then the second returns totals correctly but I find some items appearing twice with the same date but different totals

Comment: Where does "group by customer" come into this?

Comment: what are your results with this query?

Comment: do you need to add a where clause to limit your rows to the 'current day?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for 'current day' results?

```
select  item, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, date), 0) as dateInserted, 
        sum(count) as total 
from Table1
WHERE    
    dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, [date]), 0) = 
    dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
group by 
   item, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, date), 0)  
order by 1
```

If you're using SQL Server 2008, use the `DATE` datatype.

```
select  item, 
        CAST([date] as DATE)) as dateInserted, 
        sum(count) as total 
from Table1
WHERE    
    CAST([date] as DATE)) =  CAST(getdate() as DATE)
group by 
   item, CAST([date] as DATE))
order by 1
```

Comment: was on the right track thanks...inserted or where datedadd(day...getdate()-1) for the previous days results too. appreciate it.

Comment: why would I still get totals grouped twice for an item like item 20 appears twice with date 2011-03-30 but with 2 different totals

Comment: @vbNewbie: what datatype is column `item`?